# On the parity of $[x^n]$

Tags: reference-request, gm.general-mathematics

I am trying to find a problem which appeared years ago in the American Mathematical Monthly.  It went something like this:  There was a Putnam Competition question which asked to show that there is a number $x$ with the property that $[x^n]$ has the same parity as $n$ for all positive integers $n$. The square brackets indicate the floor function.  Demonstrate such a number.

Does anyone know when this problem and solution appeared?

Comment: See also https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146h150717p973568

Comment: Every element of $(-1,0)$ has this property.

Comment: I finally came upon the reference that I was looking for.  It is Problem E 3117 in The American Mathematical Monthly for December 1985 page 735

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google turns up [this "Mock Putnam Exam" from the U[niversity] of I[llinois]](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/putnam/problems/mock11.pdf), whose unattributed second problem asks to show that $[(\sqrt2+1)^n]$ has parity *opposite* to that of $n$ for each $n=1,2,3,\ldots\,$.  Perhaps that's what you remember?  (It should also be possible to make *any* infinite binary sequence arise as  $\{[x^n] \bmod 2\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for some $x$ by starting from $x$ large enough and using the sequence of conditions to define a sequence of approximations converging to $x$.)

[*added later*: an explicit example of $[x^n] \equiv n \bmod 2$ is the largest root $3.214319743377535\!\ldots$ of the cubic $x^3 - 3x^2 - x + 1$.]

Comment: It feels to me that one should be able to modify the construction of [Mills' constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) to explicitly obtain such an $x$ as the limit of a sequence something like $a_{n+1} = \sqrt[n+1]{\lfloor a_n^{n+1}\rfloor+b_n}$ (might need a little bit of tweaking; this was a back of the envelope attempt to generalize Mills' construction) where the sequence of $b_n$ is chosen according to the binary sequence one wishes to obtain per you're generalization. Is this the sort of construction you are envisioning @Noam?

Comment: @ARupinski Yes.  To get a prime between $N$ and $N+H$, we need $H$ to be some power of $N$ (it should really be a power of $\log N$ but we can't prove anything like that), which is why Mills needs double exponentials.  For an integer of given parity, $H=2$ is enough, so plain $[x^n]$ probably suffices.

Comment: $x=\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}2$ works as well.

Comment: Is the parenthetical comment supposed to be obvious? It's clear to me that we can start with any finite binary sequence, but ``the $x$ that satisfy the first $n$ constraints'', while nonempty for each $n$, may have empty intersection, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It was a guess when I wrote it (and the comment above), but meanwhile 
I thought about it a bit more and I think we can construct $x$ by
intersecting an infinite sequence of nested intervals as long as
the first interval $[x_1, x_1+1)$ has $x_1 \geq 4$ (so $4$ or $5$ will do).
The $n$-th interval has the form $[x_n, (x_n^n+1)^{1/n})$ for some 
integer $x_n$, and that puts $x^{n+1}$ in an interval of length at least 4
so its intersection with 
$\{X\in{\bf R}:\lfloor X\rfloor\equiv b_{n+1} \bmod 2\}$
must contain a semiopen interval of length $1$.
I should update my answer to incorporate this...

Comment: ...(as well as **Max Alekseyev**'s $(3+\sqrt{17})/2$ example).